# Plot of 2 equation and 3 variables

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I have two equation for `Ex(t1,t2,t)` and `Ey(t1,t2,t)`. Please,could you tell me, how I can make a plot `Ex(Ey)`?

```
Ex[t1_, t2_, t_] = ((Sin[t2] - Sin[t1])/(t1 - t2) - Cos[t])^2

Ey[t1_, t2_, t_] = (2 (Cos[t1] - Cos[t2])/(t1 - t2) - Sin[t])^2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you really have is a family of parametric curves. I would go about doing this in the following way (and you can switch out `t` for `t1` or `t2` if you want; just follow the general construction).

As an example, consider:

```
With[{t1 = 0.5, t2 = 0},
  ParametricPlot[{Ey[t1, t2, t], Ex[t1, t2, t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, AspectRatio -> 1]
 ]
```

[image]

If you want to see some general behavior, we can make a table over one of the other variables. For instance,

```
Multicolumn[
 Table[
   With[{t2 = 0}, ParametricPlot[{Ey[t1, t2, t], Ex[t1, t2, t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, AspectRatio -> 1]],
   {t1, {0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 5}}],
 3]
```

[image]

[image: animation]

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I added an animation.  Just because I can.

Comment: @wxffles. That's cute!

Answer (score 4):

If you are not after a continuous solution, then this is straightforward:

```
min = 0.;
max = 2.;
step = 0.1;

ListPlot[
  Transpose@{Flatten@
     Quiet@Table[
       Ey[x, y, z], {x, min, max, step}, {y, min, max, step}, {z, min,
         max, step}], 
    Flatten@Quiet@
      Table[Ex[x, y, z], {x, min, max, step}, {y, min, max, step}, {z,
         min, max, step}]}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Ey", "Ex"}]
```

[image]

**Explanation:** for a set `{x,y,z}` the functions `Ex[x,y,z]` and `Ey[x,y,z]` take some values, say, `E1` and `E2`, respectively. So for sure when the function `Ex` takes the value `E1`, then function `Ey` takes the value `E2`. So one needs to make a list of such pairs `{E2, E1}`. `Quiet` is because when the denominator (`t1-t2` in the definitions) is zero, then both functions are `Indeterminate`, and I didn't want to play around with discarding such values as they don't influence the plot.